# How to filter through the directory list with doesFileExist function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, io

I've managed to print the list of directory with this Haskell code:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Applicative
import System.Directory

main :: IO()
main = do
  all <- listDirectory "x:/n"
  mapM_ print all
```

But now I want to filter all with the doesFileExist function from System.Direcorty module and can't understand how to use it properly:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Applicative
import System.Directory

main :: IO()
main = do
  all <- listDirectory "x:/n"
  mapM_ print (filterM doesFileExist all)
```

the code above doesn't compile with ther error:

```
  * No instance for (Foldable IO) arising from a use of `mapM_'
* In a stmt of a 'do' block:
    mapM_ print (filterM doesFileExist all)
  In the expression:
    do all <- listDirectory "x:/n"
       mapM_ print (filterM doesFileExist all)
  In an equation for `main':
      main
        = do all <- listDirectory "x:/n"
             mapM_ print (filterM doesFileExist all)

   mapM_ print (filterM doesFileExist all)
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I guess that I've missed something fundumental, so, please, give me a hand in finding the way to understand what I am missing.
   Thanks

Comment: You can use `filterM doesFileExists all >>= mapM_ print`.

Comment: If you create and answer I will accept it as you was first. And now I understand the purpose of >>= (more or less)

Comment: If you use `do` notation with the `<-` "operator" - as you clearly have here - then you do understand the purpose of `>>=` even if you don't think you do. The answer provided by below is exactly the same as the one in the comment above - one uses `do` notation and the other an explicit `>>=`, but they mean exactly the same thing. The `do` notation is (more or less) just syntactic sugar for successive uses of `>>=`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use another `<-`:

```
main = do
  all <- listDirectory "x:/n"
  filtered <- filterM doesFileExist all
  mapM_ print filtered
```